# Grey Screen issue in SPA (angular Js + Web API)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

We are working on an application in which we are using Angularjs + webapi and making a Single Page App.

We have quite few Modal Pop-ups from Bootstrap used in the app, but we are facing an issue

-> on click of the modal button, the backdrop initializes and then is stuck with no modal. and we have to force refresh the browser. We are pulling the templates from other files into the modals.

initially for closing the modal, I've used `$(".modal.in").hide();` and the close is fine with out the "Stuck" on grey screen.

then later for init the modal itself it started to appear then I removed the fade class and removed the animations from the css but didn't help much.

Really need a promising fix.

```
$.support.transition = (function () {
  var thisBody = document.body || document.documentElement
    , thisStyle = thisBody.style
    , support = thisStyle.transition !== undefined || thisStyle.WebkitTransition !== undefined ||     thisStyle.MozTransition !== undefined || thisStyle.OTransition !== undefined
  return support
})()

// set CSS transition event type
if ( $.support.transition ) {
  transitionEnd = "TransitionEnd"
  if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
    transitionEnd = "webkitTransitionEnd"
  } else if ( $.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie ) {
    transitionEnd = "transitionend"
  } else if ( $.browser.opera ) {
    transitionEnd = "oTransitionEnd"
  }
}
```

The above code snippet was advised in some forums.

But in the Bootstrap.js Bootstrap v3.2.0 (http://getbootstrap.com)

```
function transitionEnd() {
var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

var transEndEventNames = {
  WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
  MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
  OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
  transition       : 'transitionend'
}

for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
  if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
    return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
  }
}

return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
}
```

Comment: i know this is not an answer rather a curiosity why didn't you use angular-ui  bootstrap and ng-modal service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive that includes the templates you want and launch and then control the boostrap modals from with in that directive. the external communication can be achieved in many ways my favorite using custom events watched by the directive to know when to hide or show the modals that way you can use all the bootstrap code you already have from INSIDE your directive. this can also be done through a service, not my favorite solution, but is also accepted. for more ideas look at the angular-ui project and the modal service

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Hey yes we are already using the ng-modal and we are using backdrop: 'static'. Sometimes in IE when the grids are not showing up with altered css, we give window.resize() and it fills the regions, should that be done here as well?